# Run query for multiple tables and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code, I need to run this code through over 200 tables, can I create a list and a for loop in the variable to go through all the tables and fetch the results for each? Also, how can I include the table name for each row in this query? I also need to go through a list on the column but I can't figure that out from the table list.

```
  DECLARE @table AS VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @column as varchar(50)

  set @table = 'x'
  set @column = 'y'

  declare @query as varchar(max)
  set @query = '  SELECT  CAST(MONTH(' + @column + ') AS VARCHAR(2)) + ''-'' + CAST(YEAR(' + @column + ') AS VARCHAR(4)) as date, count(*) as SRC_CNT
  FROM ' + @table +
  ' WHERE ' + @column + ' >= ''2018-01-01'' AND  ' + @column + '< ''2021-12-01''
  group BY CAST(MONTH(' + @column + ') AS VARCHAR(2)) + ''-''  +  CAST(YEAR(' + @column + ') AS VARCHAR(4))
  order by date;'

  exec(@query)
```

Comment: MySQL <> Sql Server, which is it?  Looksl ike SQL Server

Comment: I've removed the tag [[tag:mysql]] as the above is clearly T-SQL. Please use tags correctly.

Comment: You need to query the system tables such as `sys.tables`, `sys.columns` and formulate your desired query using the schema, tables and columns. There's plenty on Stack Overflow and the web on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than loop, I would create a dynamic batch, with all the statements you need, which you can then execute. You can use your best friend to debug the statement(s) if needed:

```sql
DECLARE @Column sysname = N'y',
        @DateFrom date = '20180101',
        @DateTo date = '20211201';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(N'SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10),' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + N',105),7) AS [Date],' + @CRLF +
                         --N'       N' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],'''') + N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF + --Uncomment this line if you need it.
                         N'       COUNT(*) AS SRC_CNT' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + @CRLF +
                         N'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + N' >= @DateFrom AND ' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + N' < @DateTo' + @CRLF +
                         N'GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10),' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + N',105),7)' + @CRLF +
                         N'ORDER BY [date];',@CRLF)
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM sys.columns c
              WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                AND c.[name] = @Column);

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@DateFrom date, @DateTo date', @DateFrom, @DateTo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Given tables and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(y date, r int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.y(y date, r int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.z(y date, r int);

INSERT dbo.x(y,r) VALUES('20180105',5),
                  ('20180107',6),('20180509',7);
INSERT dbo.y(y,r) VALUES('20180905',5),
                  ('20181007',6),('20181009',7);
INSERT dbo.z(y,r) VALUES('20180605',5),
                  ('20180607',6),('20180609',7);
```

This dynamic SQL can be generated:

```
DECLARE @col       sysname = N'y',
        @StartDate date    = '20180101',
        @EndDate   date    = '20211201';


DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @base nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT [Table Name] = $tblQ$, 
    [date] = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR($col$), MONTH($col$), 1), 
    SRC_CNT = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.$tbl$ WHERE $col$ >= @s AND y < @e
  GROUP BY YEAR($col$), MONTH($col$)';
  
SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
        (@base, N'$tblQ$', QUOTENAME(t.name, char(39))
        ),N'$tbl$',QUOTENAME(t.name)), N'$col$', @col), N'
   UNION ALL
   ') + ' ORDER BY [date];'
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
    AND name = @col);
  
  PRINT @sql;

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, 
       N'@s date, @e date', 
       @StartDate, @EndDate;
```

Which produces a query like this (only tables that actually have that column name, could be made even safer by making sure they're using a date/time type):

```
SELECT [Table Name] = 'x', 
    [date] = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(y), MONTH(y), 1), 
    SRC_CNT = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.[x] WHERE y >= @s AND y < @e
  GROUP BY YEAR(y), MONTH(y)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Table Name] = 'y', 
    [date] = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(y), MONTH(y), 1), 
    SRC_CNT = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.[y] WHERE y >= @s AND y < @e
  GROUP BY YEAR(y), MONTH(y)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Table Name] = 'z', 
    [date] = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(y), MONTH(y), 1), 
    SRC_CNT = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.[z] WHERE y >= @s AND y < @e
  GROUP BY YEAR(y), MONTH(y) ORDER BY [date];
```

That generates output like this:

| Table Name | date | SRC_CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2018-01-01 | 2 |
| x | 2018-05-01 | 1 |
| z | 2018-06-01 | 3 |
| y | 2018-09-01 | 1 |
| y | 2018-10-01 | 2 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=837a3c81597ac43cdb85bff1c19b8911)

If you really want `yyyy-MM` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd` on the output, you can [just change this line in the declaration of `@base`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e01a1b486e4fccbaecc1467a9acca05a):

```
[date] = CONVERT(char(7), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR($col$), MONTH($col$), 1), 120),
```

And I realized the requirement was `MM-yyyy`, in which case:

```
[date] = RIGHT(CONVERT(char(10), 
         DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR($col$), MONTH($col$), 1), 105), 7),
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually do the following for tables:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM [<DATABASE_NAME>].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

You said you could handle columns from there.